# how to have 0 or 1 repeat of token with javaCC

Tags: java, javacc

I want to use javaCC to generate a parser.

But I have a problem.
(+) is for 1 or more repeat
(*) is for 0 or more repeat

But how can I choice 0 or 1 repeat?

For example, I want this string :

```
"Monday thursday wednesday"
```

`"Monday thursday"` work also

`"Monday wednesday"` work also

`"wednesday"` work also.

So I have to have a list of days of week with 1 or 0 repeat.

```
| < MONDAY: "MONDAY" >
| < THURSDAY: "THURSDAY" >
| < WEDNESDAY: "WEDNESDAY" >
```

I have tried :

```
void period() :
{
}
{        
       (< MONDAY>){0,1} (< THURSDAY>){0,1} (< WEDNESDAY>){0,1}
}
```

but it doesn't work...

Someone can help me and understand my problem? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Does order matter? If it's ok to require given order, then just "optional MONDAY, optional THURSDAY, optional WEDNESDAY". Otherwise you do "repeat { MONDAY or THURSDAY or WEDNESDAY }" and you get no guarantee that a value doesn't occur more than once. You have to validate that in the code using the parsed result.

Comment: and if order matter? it exists a solution?
And if order doesn't matter, how use optional keyword? Thanks !

Comment: I believe I just gave two alternate solutions in the comment. Try reading it again.

Comment: Ok i use  (< MONDAY>)? (< THURSDAY>)? and it seeems to work !